# сделать img с alpha из jpeg не на canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

думаю как сделать изображение с альфа каналом из jpg без использования canvas т.к. такая обработка каждый раз задерживает готовность страницы и сильно зависит от производительности железа пользователя
новое свойство с применением альфа масок тоже не приемлемо не везде правильно отображается

вот из такой картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно получить такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если треугольник где alpha должен быть полностью прозрачным, то можно отрезать часть картинки при помощи svg.

```html
<svg with=322 height=322>
  <clipPath id="clipTriangle">
    <polygon points="0 0,0 322,322 0">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>

  <image clip-path="url(#clipTriangle)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG66c.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="322px" width="322px"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: как раз то что нужно СПАСИБО ОГРОМЕННОЕ

Answer (score 0):

чуть чуть подправил чтоб работало

```
<svg id="_1" data-name="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=400 height=400>

<clipPath id="clipTriangle">
    <polygon points="0 0,0 400,400 0">
    </polygon>
</clipPath>

<image clip-path="url(#clipTriangle)" xlink:href="you_file.jpg" width="400" height="400" />

</svg>
```